Only bottom row of Flexbox Gallery in clickable
I'm trying to create a Flexbox gallery that is responsive to browser width (ie. wraps and auto creates rows) where you can click on the image to open up a full size version of the image on it's own page.
I've run it an issue where for some reason, the links are only working (including the pointer hover) on the images on the bottom row.
<div class="gallery-container">
            <a class="gallery-photo" href="1.png">
                <img src="1.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="gallery-photo" href="2.png">
                <img src="2.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="gallery-photo" href="3.png">
                <img src="3.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="gallery-photo" href="4.png">
                <img src="4.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="gallery-photo" href="5.png">
                <img src="5.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="gallery-photo" href="6.png">
                <img src="6.png" alt="">
            </a>
            <a class="gallery-photo" href="7.png">
                <img src="7.png" alt="">
            </a>
</div>

.gallery-container {
    display: flex;
    max-width: 90vw;
    width: 750px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.gallery-photo {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 200px;
}

I have a live test link that show the error/issue: https://nickvn33.github.io/Yoshin_testbed/Gallery.html
You'll also notice if you hide the photo on the bottom line, photos 4-6 become clickable

Please create a runnable snippet that you’ve tested does indeed show the problem. Use <> in the editor.

I have a live test link that show the error/issue: https://nickvn33.github.io/Yoshin_testbed/Gallery.html
You'll also notice if you hide the photo on the bottom line, photos 4-6 become clickable

You need to create a snippet that shows the problem. I did look at your link (there's no point in having a link in a question for future readers as obviously you will mend the bug there!). Your problem is the z-idex: -1 on content. You need to rethink the way you lay the page out.

The code you have included does not reproduce the problem.


.gallery-container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 90vw;
  width: 750px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 1em;
}

.gallery-photo {
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<div class="gallery-container">
  <a class="gallery-photo" href="https://picsum.photos/id/770/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/770/100/200">
  </a>
  <a class="gallery-photo" href="https://picsum.photos/id/764/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/764/110/200">
  </a>
  <a class="gallery-photo" href="https://picsum.photos/id/765/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/765/120/200">
  </a>
  <a class="gallery-photo" href="https://picsum.photos/id/766/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/766/130/200">
  </a>
  <a class="gallery-photo" href="https://picsum.photos/id/767/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/767/140/200">
  </a>
  <a class="gallery-photo" href="https://picsum.photos/id/768/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/768/150/200">
  </a>
  <a class="gallery-photo" href="https://picsum.photos/id/769/500">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/769/160/200">
  </a>
</div>




issue was with the z-index of the container
